# How do I specify that a tab be four space characters in Text Wrangler?

Tags: textwrangler

I tried to specify a tab to be four spaces in Text Wrangler by checking "Preferences" -> "Editor Defaults" -> "Auto-expand tabs."

However, tabs still comprise of tab characters with each tab having the width of 4 spaces.

Comment: try closing, then re-opening the program

Comment: It's still not working for some reason after reopening Text Wrangler. I know it's not working because I cannot move my cursor through the tab as if it were spaces. Also, after opening the document in vim, I cannot do this either.

Comment: You created that file with no auto-expand. TextWrangler remembers the state of this document. The preferences only apply to new files. You need to set auto-expand for this file in the file's toolbar (click on the T-icon to see a dropdown list with this option).

Comment: The last comment worked for me. TextStrangler remembering settings per file must be the worst feature in history...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a special type of document, you might try Preferences > Languages. Select the language the document content is, then go to Options... > Editing and select "Auto-expand tabs", then click "Save."

Comment: This didn't work for Python. Version 4.5.9

Answer (score 0):

For TextWrangler 5.5.1, use 'Text -> Detab ...' to removed existing tabs. To have new tabs inserted as spaces, while editing the document click on the tools icon on the left of the navigation bar, and select 'auto-expand tabs'.